# TSQL Scalar Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I created a small function that takes a few date params and outputs a project status based on some logic I defined.

I am trying to figure out how I can "Break Out" of the function once a status has been set though. In my logic below, it seems that its always going to check the `dueDate` and set its status and then overwrite it self with the following check.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fetch_TaskStatus]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @startDate DATE = NULL,
    @dueDate DATE = NULL,
    @completionDate DATE = NULL
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @status varchar(100);

    -- Declare our current date
    DECLARE @now DATE = GETUTCDATE();

    -- Logic
    -- If our start date and completion date are missing..
    IF(@startDate IS NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL)
        BEGIN

            -- If our due date is past the current date, its past due
            IF(@dueDate < @now)
            BEGIN
                SET @status = 'Past Due';
            END

            -- We have a start date but the task has not been started.
            SET @status = 'Inactive';

        END

        -- If we have a start date and no completion date
    IF(@startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL)
        BEGIN

            -- Are we past due?
            IF(@dueDate < @now)
                BEGIN
                    SET @status = 'Past Due'
                END

            -- We are not past due, must be in progress
            SET @status = 'In Progress'

        END

    -- If we have a start date and a completion date
    IF(@startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NOT NULL)

        BEGIN
            -- We have started and completed our task
            SET @status = 'Complete'
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @status

END
```

Once a status has been set, I need to break out of this function so the status is not overwritten again by the logic that follows it.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why not just `RETURN` from within the `IF` statements instead of setting a variable?

Comment: why not just `RETURN` early? or use nested `IF` blocks if you want to stick to "only 1 return statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fetch_TaskStatus]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@startDate DATE = NULL,
@dueDate DATE = NULL,
@completionDate DATE = NULL
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @status varchar(100);

-- Declare our current date
DECLARE @now DATE = GETUTCDATE();

-- Logic
-- If our start date and completion date are missing..
IF(@startDate IS NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL)
    BEGIN

        -- If our due date is past the current date, its past due
        IF(@dueDate < @now)
        BEGIN
            RETURN  'Past Due';

        END

        -- We have a start date but the task has not been started.
            RETURN  'Inactive';

    END

    -- If we have a start date and no completion date
IF(@startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL)
    BEGIN

        -- Are we past due?
        IF(@dueDate < @now)
            BEGIN
            RETURN  'Past Due'

            END

        -- We are not past due, must be in progress
            RETURN  'In Progress'

    END

-- If we have a start date and a completion date
IF(@startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        -- We have started and completed our task
            RETURN  'Complete'
    END

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN 'Unknown';

END
```

You can also make use of `IF-ELSE` block. I have rewrite it using `IF-ELSE` too, just check if your logic is guaranteed yet or not:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fetch_TaskStatus]
    (
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @startDate DATE = NULL ,
      @dueDate DATE = NULL ,
      @completionDate DATE = NULL
    )
 RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
    BEGIN

-- Declare our current date
        DECLARE @now DATE = GETUTCDATE();

-- Logic
-- If our start date and completion date are missing..
        IF ( @startDate IS NULL
             AND @completionDate IS NULL
           )
            BEGIN
         -- If our due date is past the current date, its past due
                IF ( @dueDate < @now )
                    RETURN  'Past Due';
                ELSE
                        -- We have a start date but the task has not been started.
                    RETURN  'Inactive';
            END;

    -- If we have a start date and no completion date
        IF ( @startDate IS NOT NULL
             AND @completionDate IS NULL
           )
            BEGIN
            -- Are we past due?
                IF ( @dueDate < @now )
                    RETURN  'Past Due';
                ELSE
                        -- We are not past due, must be in progress
                    RETURN  'In Progress';
            END;

-- If we have a start date and a completion date
        IF ( @startDate IS NOT NULL
             AND @completionDate IS NOT NULL
           )
            -- We have started and completed our task
            RETURN  'Complete';

      -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN 'Unknown';
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a completely different approach here? Scalar functions are horribly inefficient and not very flexible. Usually a better approach is to use an inline table valued function. This means you have to use a single select statement. Of course your whole series of nested IF statements could be compressed to a couple case expressions. This is far simpler to maintain, more flexible and will perform better.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fetch_TaskStatus]
(
    @startDate DATE = NULL,
    @dueDate DATE = NULL,
    @completionDate DATE = NULL
)
RETURNS table as return
    select TaskStatus = 
        Case
            WHEN @startDate IS NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL then
                Case when @dueDate < GETUTCDATE() then 'Past Due' else 'Inactive' end

            WHEN @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL then
                Case when @dueDate < GETUTCDATE() then 'Past Due' else 'In Progress' end
            WHEN @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NOT NULL then 'Complete'
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fetch_TaskStatus] (
     -- Add the parameters for the function here
     @startDate DATE = NULL,
     @dueDate DATE = NULL,
     @completionDate DATE = NULL
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS 
    BEGIN
    -- Declare our current date
        DECLARE @now DATE = GETUTCDATE();

        RETURN CASE WHEN @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Complete'
                    WHEN @dueDate < @now THEN 'Past Due'
                    WHEN @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL THEN 'In Progress'
                    WHEN @startDate IS NULL AND @completionDate IS NULL THEN 'Inactive'
                    END
    END
```

this should cover your logic